# How do I debug overridden twig templates?

Tags: theming, debugging

How do I debug the template overrides. The debugger stops on page.html.twig but doesn't stop on sub templates such as

web/themes/custom/localtheme/templates/field--paragraph--field-pbcrossfade-image--crossfade-banner.html.twig

The page.html.twig breaks here

[image]

The debugger does not break in the sub template.

[image]

Comment: What about immediately after a cache rebuild?

Comment: Bizarrely it doesn't break on the first page load after a page rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `{{ breakpoint }}` is a valid twig function to have a PHP pause.

If you have the module devel installed, you can use `{{ devel_breakpoint() }}`

Otherwise you can use `{{ drupal_breakpoint() }}` if you have Twig Tweak installed.

Documentation : https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/twig-tweak-2x/cheat-sheet#s-drupal-breakpoint